# Receiving wrong output from XElement

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'm trying to use XElement to write this XML:

```
<FilterItems>
 <FilterItem FilterItemId="63777">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM</FilterItem>
 <FilterItem FilterItemId="63778">4/20/2015 12:00:00 PM</FilterItem>
</FilterItems>
```

Here is what I'm trying:

```
  public XElement XmElement()
    {
        XElement element = new XElement("FilterItems",
                           new XElement("FilterItem", "FilterItemId=\"63777\">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM"),
                           new XElement("FilterItem", "FilterItemId=\"63778\">4/20/2015 12:00:00 PM"));

        return element;
    }
```

And here is the output I'm getting:

```
 <FilterItems>
   <FilterItem>FilterItemId="63777"&gt;4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM</FilterItem>
   <FilterItem>FilterItemId="63778"&gt;4/20/2015 12:00:00 PM</FilterItem>
 </FilterItems>
```

There are two problems that need to be fixed:

1) FilterItemId="63777">
Comparing to the original, the right angle bracket shouldn't be after FilterItem

2) I'd like to avoid the ">" from being escaped and be maintained as xml

I need the output to be exactly as the original. Thanks!

**Modification 1:**

```
 public XElement XmElement()
    {
        XElement element = new XElement("FilterItems",
                           new XElement("FilterItem FilterItemId=\"63777\">","4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM"),
                           new XElement("FilterItem FilterItemId=\"63778\">","4/20/2015 12:00:00 PM"));

        return element;
    }
```

Receiving error: "The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."

Comment: You're confusing elements and attributes.  The XML being generated is correct as far as the LINQ to XML knows.   You told it to create an element named "FilterItem", with the specified inner text (e.g., `FilterItemId="6377">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM`).  `>` is a special character in XML, so it is represented by `&gt;` to prevent parsers from breaking.

Comment: Made a modification addition to the original post include FilterItemId="6377" as part of the element and receiving an error. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    XElement element = new XElement("FilterItems",
                        new XElement("FilterItem",
                           new XAttribute("FilterItemId", 63777),
                           "4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM"),
                        new XElement("FilterItem",
                           new XAttribute("FilterItemId", 63778),
                           "4/20/2015 12:00:00 PM") 
                           );
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Print:

```
<FilterItems>
  <FilterItem FilterItemId="63777">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM</FilterItem>
  <FilterItem FilterItemId="63778">4/20/2015 12:00:00 PM</FilterItem>
</FilterItems>
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VxkjT0

Comment: Just learning this stuff and didn't realize there was an XAttribute item available.  Makes sense.